# I have tried to open "Jetsurveysample" from compose jetpack samples, but getting a build error, although I am using latest Android Studio 4.2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

This version of the Android Support plugin for IntelliJ IDEA (or Android Studio) cannot open this project, please retry with version 4.3 or newer.

Comment: That sample is probably set up for the Canary edition of Android Studio 2020.3.1.

Answer (score 1):

For Jetpack Compose Sample Apps you currently need the Arctic Fox Canary build of Android Studio, which can be found here: https://developer.android.com/studio/preview

Details on how to try the sample apps are on this page: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/setup

Once you have the correct version of Android Studio, all you need to do is select "Import an Android code sample", type compose in the search bar to select the sample app that you want, click Next and Finish.